# My Mineflayer bot doesn't respond to my message

Tags: javascript, mineflayer

I'm using MineFlayer JS to make a basic bot that responds to a user's message. Here is the source code. The issue I'm having is that it doesn't respond to my chat message when I type /msg bot test in chat.

```js
// Importing the necessary modules
const mineflayer = require('mineflayer')

// Options for the bot
const options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 53115,
    username: 'bot'
}

// Creating the actual bot
const bot = mineflayer.createBot(options)

// Creating a function to say "Hey I am a bot." in minecraft chat and logs "I spawned." in console
function typeHiInChat() {
    bot.chat("Hey! I am a bot.")
    console.log('I spawned.')
}

// Creating a function to say "I have been kicked from the server!" open it getting kicked
function onKick() {
    console.log('I have been kicked from the server!')
}

// Setting up a listener that listens for the 'spawn' event
bot.once('spawn', typeHiInChat)

// Setting up a listener that listens for the 'kick' event
bot.once('kicked', onKick)

bot.on('message', (message, jsonMSG) => {
    msg = JSON.stringify(jsonMSG)
    if (msg == "test") {
        bot.chat("This Works!")
    }
})
```

It doesn't respond to my chat message when I type /msg test in my Minecraft chat. It does say "Hey! I am a bot." in chat, but not the actual thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the 'chat' event as it appears you're not using the 'message' event properly, where the first parameter is the jsonMSG and the 2nd is the position. Take a look here
https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer/blob/master/docs/api.md#events

Based on this, this is an example that should work

```js
bot.on('chat', (username, message) => {
  if (username === bot.username) return
  if(message === 'test') bot.chat("This Works!") 
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use any functions for chat just simply use bot.chat()`bot.on('chat', (username,message)=>{if(message === 'hi'){bot.chat('Hi')}})`
this automatically updates the bot on chat so u dont have to use settintervals and if u want the bot to respond to specific chat just use if of else if statements